# How to subset over a string of times

Tags: r

In R I have a dataframe `data`.

```
head (data) gives
ID   sign_in
21   23:50:21
12   10:11:38
...
```

that contains ID and the sign in time for that ID. Both columns are strings (or characters).
Say I want a subset of `data` that only contains ID in the time interval from 10 o'clcok to 11 o'clock.

This is how I tried to solve it:

```
data_new = subset(data, data[,2] %in% as.character(10:00:00) : as.character(11:00:00) )
```

but R gives an error message saying **ERROR: unexpected constant**

How can I solve this?

Comment: What did you expect from R to do for `as.character(10:00:00) : as.character(11:00:00)`? R parser parses from inside out. So first, it was trying to parse `10:00:00`, but `:` can only handle `10:0`, then, this vector was converted to character, same thing with the second vector. Then, you've tried to run `:` on two character vectors, but `:` function can accept only scalar values and etc. You should really try braking your code into parts: `10:00:00` then `as.character(10:00:00)` etc. Either-way, try `library(data.table) ; as.ITime("23:50:21") %in% (as.ITime("10:00:00") : as.ITime("11:00:00"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the character column to `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` format by,

```
df$sign_in <- as.POSIXct(df$sign_in,format="%H:%M:%S")
```

and then subset,

```
df[df$sign_in > as.POSIXct("10:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S") &
     df$sign_in < as.POSIXct("11:00:00", format="%H:%M:%S"), ]
```